# Where does Preview save a clone of a document?

Tags: preview

I have a document with a base64 name that I have hit `shift command s` to make a copy and then hit `command s` to save it.  The "*" in the title bar is gone now so it has been saved. *But *where* ..*  It is not in the same directory as the original file and it is not anywhere underneath my home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out where it went to: it is from some prior "File Save" *from a different application (not Preview!)*. It is *not possible to re-specify - or even _see !_ - the directory when using the `Duplicate` functionality*. Instead it is necessary to use the `File | Rename`.  That is a bug imo.